# Ionic scroll after page has loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic2, and need to scroll a list to a specific position when the page loads.

I do the following:

```
  public ionViewDidEnter(): void {
    if (this.content) {
      this.content.scrollTo(0, this.lastScrollPos, 0);
    }
  }
```

**Problem**

This works, but my problem is even though the scroll time is 0, the scroll animation is still visible to the user.

**Question**

Is there a way to do the scroll, but it is not apparent to the user?  I have tried doing the scroll in `ionViewWillEnter`, but it does not scroll because I think this is too early and the list doesn't exist yet.

Thanks

Comment: How about this.content._scroll.setTop(this.lastScrollPos);

Comment: Hi Misha130, thanks for the comment. This works, but the same as my current solution. The scroll animation is still visible to the user.

Comment: Ok How about @ContentChild(Content) public set content(c:Content) { if(c) this.c.scrollTo(0, this.lastScrollPos, 0); } Basically the second the ContentChild is defined move the scroll. This is the earliest. I think this is also normal behavior for a Web View to animation the scrolling process and not just stick it in a place. You could also hide the content until you scrolled it back.

Comment: Thanks, how would you hide the content, and then display it again?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#input-properties) you can add the `scrollDownOnLoad="true"` attribute: _If true, the content will scroll down on load._. Have you already tried with that?

Comment: Hi sebaferreras, Thanks, but `scrollDownOnLoad ` won't work for me because I want to scroll to a specific point, and not down to the bottom.

Comment: Hi misha130, I don't really understand what you mean by `@ContentChild(Content) public set content(c:Content) { if(c) this.c.scrollTo(0, this.lastScrollPos, 0); } `. How does setting the `@ContentChild` make a difference?

Comment: Its the first thing that is set in ts. Before ionviewdidenter I assume

Answer (score 0):

You can implement in your constructor like:

```
constructor(viewCtrl: ViewController) {
this._viewCtrlWriteSub = viewCtrl.writeReady.subscribe(() => {
    this._viewCtrlWriteSub.unsubscribe();
    this.content.scrollTo(0, this.lastScrollPos, 0);
});
```

}

that's it